# fortran syntax eorr while using DATA statement to initialize an array

Tags: fortran

I encountered the following Fortran code which cannot be compiled using `gfortran`:

```
  CHARACTER(LEN=20) :: filename(max_xoms,2)
  DATA(filename = RESHAPE(SOURCE=(/'XobsXOM0.txt','XobsXOM1.txt','XobsXOM2.txt','XobsXOM3.txt','XobsXOM4.txt',  &
                                   'XobsXOM5.txt','XobsXOM6.txt','XobsXOM7.txt','XobsXOM8.txt','XobsXOM9.txt',  &
                                   'XobsXOS0.txt','XobsXOS1.txt','XobsXOS2.txt','XobsXOS3.txt','XobsXOS4.txt',  &
                                   'XobsXOS5.txt','XobsXOS6.txt','XobsXOS7.txt','XobsXOS8.txt','XobsXOS9.txt'/),  &
                                   SHAPE=(/max_xoms,2/)))
```

The `makefile` that comes with the code uses `ifort`. I changed the compiler to `gfortran` and got an error message while compiling the above:

```
gfortran  -c -fbacktrace -ffree-line-length-none -Wall hype_indata.f90
hype_indata.f90:48.16:

  DATA(filename = RESHAPE(SOURCE=(/'XobsXOM0.txt','XobsXOM1.txt','XobsXOM2.txt'
                1
Error: Syntax error in DATA statement at (1)
```

I've tried removing `=` at `1`, but that doesn't fix the statement.

Can anyone please explain how should I fix this statement?

Thanks

BTW, `gfortran --version` returns:

```
GNU Fortran (tdm64-2) 4.8.1
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if `max_oms` is a `parameter` (i.e. a constant, and it probably is one) you can do:

```
CHARACTER(LEN=20) :: filename(max_xoms,2) = RESHAPE(SOURCE=(/'XobsXOM0.txt','XobsXOM1.txt','XobsXOM2.txt','XobsXOM3.txt','XobsXOM4.txt',  &
                                   'XobsXOM5.txt','XobsXOM6.txt','XobsXOM7.txt','XobsXOM8.txt','XobsXOM9.txt',  &
                                   'XobsXOS0.txt','XobsXOS1.txt','XobsXOS2.txt','XobsXOS3.txt','XobsXOS4.txt',  &
                                   'XobsXOS5.txt','XobsXOS6.txt','XobsXOS7.txt','XobsXOS8.txt','XobsXOS9.txt'/),  &
                                   SHAPE=(/max_xoms,2/))
```

otherwise move

```
filename = RESHAPE(SOURCE=(/'XobsXOM0.txt','XobsXOM1.txt','XobsXOM2.txt','XobsXOM3.txt','XobsXOM4.txt',  &
                                   'XobsXOM5.txt','XobsXOM6.txt','XobsXOM7.txt','XobsXOM8.txt','XobsXOM9.txt',  &
                                   'XobsXOS0.txt','XobsXOS1.txt','XobsXOS2.txt','XobsXOS3.txt','XobsXOS4.txt',  &
                                   'XobsXOS5.txt','XobsXOS6.txt','XobsXOS7.txt','XobsXOS8.txt','XobsXOS9.txt'/),  &
                                   SHAPE=(/max_xoms,2/))
```

to the position of a first executable statement.

Generally, avoid `DATA` in Fortran 90 and later.